# How to import c enum in swift

Tags: c, swift

When I import my c enum into swift, it becomes a struct and loses the cases. How can I get this to import as an enum in swift?

c code:

```
enum Foo {
    A = 1,
    B = 2
};
```

Generated Swift:

```
public struct Foo : Equatable, RawRepresentable {

    public init(_ rawValue: UInt32)

    public init(rawValue: UInt32)

    public var rawValue: UInt32
}
```

Expected Swift:

```
enum Foo: UInt32 {
    case A = 1,
    case B = 2
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Swift imports usual C-enums, cases are imported as global constants.

As if as follows:

```
let A = Foo(1)
let B = Foo(2)
```

You can use them like this:

```
var someFoo: Foo = A
```

I'm not sure why these constants are not included in the Generated Interface.

---

If you can touch your .h file and can import some headers for Objective-C classes, you can use the macro `NS_ENUM`.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Bar) {
    A = 1,
    B = 2
};
```

The generated header would be like this:

```
public enum Bar : Int {


    case A

    case B
}
```

(Generated Interface does not show `rawValue`s, but they are 1 and 2 respectively as in the original code.)

But I wonder if this can be your option.

Comment: I was able to do this with CF_ENUM since it's a C API. I have a custom define that is CF_ENUM when compiling for iOS and defined as something else when compiling for the microcontroller.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60559599/1187415)  may be useful when the enumeration is defined in a “pure” C header.