# Swift - C API enum in Swift

Tags: c, swift, enums

I have C API defined like this:

```
typedef enum Foo {
   A = 0,
   B = 1
} Foo;

typedef struct Bar {
  int a;
  Foo foo;
} Bar;
```

How can I use `Foo` enum in Swift directly? I know, that I can do `var data: Foo = A`, but I dont like this syntax, where `A` seems to be some global variable.

I would rather have `var data: Foo = Foo.A` or something similar like with standard enums. Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C enumerations are imported into Swift as an `enum` if they are defined via the `NS_ENUM` or `CF_ENUM` macro, see for example [How to import c enum in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845357/how-to-import-c-enum-in-swift/52846808#52846808).

`CF_ENUM` is defined in `CFAvailability.h` from the Core Foundation framework, so you have to import that file if it is not yet imported indirectly via other Core Foundation include files:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CFAvailability.h>

typedef CF_ENUM(int, Foo) {
    A = 0,
    B = 1
};
```

If you lookup the definition of `CF_ENUM` then you'll see that it is defined in terms of the Clang [`enum_extensibility`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#enum-extensibility) attribute, and expands to

```
typedef enum __attribute__((enum_extensibility(open))) : int {
    A = 0,
    B = 1
} Foo;
```

Both declarations are imported to Swift as

```
public enum Foo : Int32 {
    case A
    case B
}
```

and the latter version does not need additional include files.

(For the difference between “open” and “closed” enums, see [SE 0192 Handling Future Enum Cases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md).)